# Is there any means by which I can restart a thread?

Tags: .net, multithreading

As I was going through MSDN on the threading topic I found out that if a thread has been terminated it can't be restarted once again, if we try to do so we get an exception. [Over Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a9fyxz7d.aspx)

I was wondering that is there any means by which we can restart the thread to do the same job, MSDN is silent about this ?

Thanks

Comment: In java you get `Executor` framework which works with `tasks` and relieve programmer from thinking about how to manage threads most of the time. Guess, .NET must have something similar.

Comment: Well, if the user code run by a thread has to do the same job more than once, it's usual to use a loop, ie. don't let the thread terminate.  The OS provides plenty mechanisms to make thread wait for more work, (hence ThreadPool, where threads wait for work).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no way of restarting the thread. On the other hand, if you remember the `ThreadStart` or `ParameterizedThreadStart` you gave when creating the thread, you can start another one with the same delegate. Note that that will start the delegate again though, from scratch - if you were trying to "keep going" from where the thread had got to, you'll need to store that state somewhere.

I can't say I've ever wanted to do this though - what's your use case? There may be a better approach.

Comment: What do you mean by "if you were trying to "keep going" from where the thread had got to, you'll need to store that state somewhere." And how to do that ?

Comment: @Bibhu: Well it would depend on what you were trying to do. For example, if you were processing a list of items, you'd need to make that list available to other code so it knew how far you'd got.